# How to make the presentViewController with SLComposeViewController faster?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am opening the Twitter compose view on my app, but the screen takes too long to be displayed!

I started using the following code when the user taps the twitter button:

```
 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

    SLComposeViewController *tweet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [tweet setInitialText:@"initial text "];


    [self presentViewController:tweet animated:YES completion:^
     {

     }];
}
```

But it takes between 5 and 8 seconds to show the screen! For me it's too long, I saw apps that goes instantly. It is not an issue with my app, because I have created a new project with only this functionality, and it takes the same.

So I thought that the delay was in the moment that the screen is instantiated, so I have decided to declare my tweet screen on my header and moved  this part to the viewDidAppear:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

tweet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[tweet setInitialText:@"initial text "];
```

and on the button method is like that:

```
if(tweet)
[self presentViewController:tweet animated:YES completion:^
 {

 }];
```

but it didn't get faster. I am using an iPhone 4 and I have some apps that creates the twitter compose screen really fast, does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Unless there is a thread consuming piece of code that you've left out this shouldn't be happening. Have you enabled slow animations in the simulator?

Comment: Hey @0x7fffffff.. thank for you reply.. I didn't even know that is possible to enable slow animations.. =) Anyway I am using the device to test..

Comment: Yeah, it can be really helpful when you're trying to make sure something is animating right. And is there any code directly above this in your function?

Comment: Also having this issue on the iPhone 4 with iOS 7.0.3 - really frustrating!

Comment: I started a topic on the Apple Developer forums so maybe we can get an answer there. https://devforums.apple.com/message/920016

Comment: I am having the same problem on the device. iOS 7.1. Slow as hell. Have you find a solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: The presentation animation is very slow and choppy for me as well. Any solution?

Comment: No.. not really @max_

Comment: Here's a workaround that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38964293/1322108

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue -- it was driving me crazy. I fixed it by dispatch_async on the main queue

```
// Perform this on the main queue
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    __strong __typeof(self) strongLocalSelf = weakSelf;


        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:@"Share message"];
        [controller addURL:@"http://www.someURL.com"];
        [strongLocalSelf presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been bugging me as well for a whole day! Finally i get some trick to make the SLComposeViewController appear faster. Its seems when I want to load the SLComposeVC for the first time, The SLComposer will take a lot of resource in main thread, but after that, its will appear perfectly normal without delay... so I guess maybe we need to load the SLCompose View in our view controller (just load the view) and viola.. the SLComposerView will be directly presented into the view...

Just add this code in your appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  ....

//loading the view...make twitter share dialog appear with no dellay
    if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil){
        SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [composeViewController view];
    }
   ...
}
```

- sorry if my English is not perfect, I'm not a native.

Comment: this doesn't seem to help unfortunately